# How are transistors on processor chips designed to withstand high operating temperatures?

Tags: transistors, processor

The process for transistors grow smaller every  few years, and operating temperatures reach around 100 degree Celsius. This makes one wonder as to how these tiny designs are able to hold up within these conditions without breaking down. Specifically what factors other than the materials used (if any) could contribute to this resistance to heat.

As someone from outside the electrical field of expertise, I would appreciate it if the answer is put in layman terms as well.

Comment: Remember that the components are metals and metal oxides. Is 100C a "high" temperature for a metal?

Comment: Thermal conductivity from substrate to package to heatsink is an important design factor.

Answer (score 3):

The **size** of a transistor has **nothing** to do with how able it is to withstand high temperatures. The temperature has a more or less similar effect on all devices, large and small.

At high temperatures there is more **stress** on the devices and that mostly results in higher leakage currents (current flow when the device is off and ideally no current should flow) and potential damage to devices and the connections between devices.

One important effect at high temperatures is [Electromigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration) which is an effect that can **damage** the connections (metal tracks) in a chip and that can eventually break the chip making it unusable. Electromigration is **very** temperature dependent so chip designs must be made such that this effect is not an issue even if a chip operates at high temperatures (for example 90 degrees C) over its lifetime (for example 10 years of continuous operation).

From your question it appears that you think that operating temperatures are increasing. Well, they're not. Depending on the manufacturer the maximum operating temperature is usually around 90 C to 100 C. Modern CPUs monitor their own temperature and slow down (throttle down) when they get too hot. That means they do not allow themselves to get hotter than 90 C or 100 C.

If a manufacturer would choose to increase that maximum operating temperature to for example 120 C then that **will** impact the lifetime of the chip. If you used such a chip like most users do then probably it will last you a lifetime.

But if you use that same CPU for mining cryptocurrency so it operates at 120 C continuously then its lifetime might be shortened significantly. Maybe it breaks after a few months. You could then complain to the manufacturer that the chip was faulty. So the chip manufacturer limits the operating temperature to such a value that they can **guarantee** a long lifetime (say 10 years) of continuous operation at that temperature.

If you want a more in-depth understanding of the deterioration of semiconductors (chips) due to high temperature then you will need to study semiconductors and PN junctions. It is complicated material and not something that can be explained here or even in "layman's terms".

Comment: It's precisely effects like Electromagnetism and design decisions to combat them that I'm worrying about (conditions brought about by high temperatures). The wiki article you linked does state that the practical significance of this effect increases as structure size decreases. Would it be correct to infer from that statement that the size of the transistor does become a factor here(albeit balanced by design decisions)? 
I must also clarify that I do not imply operating temperatures increase every year, just that operating temperatures are quite high.

Comment: Of course, it's understandable that this could be something that goes into much more detail than can be handled in layman's terms, and I wouldn't press further.

Comment: *Would it be correct to infer from that statement that the size of the transistor does become a factor here* It is more a secondary effect, to be able to effectively use small transistors you also need small interconnect (wiring) otherwise the interconnect determines the size, not the transistors. So both (interconnect size and transistor size) are related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms, you make transistors by adding various materials to silicon, and then heating them up so they diffuse into it. You stop heating when they've diffused in just the right distance to create the correct structure.

If you continue heating at high temperature, then the materials will continue to move, eventually stopping the device working again.

Diffusion is exponentially temperature dependent. At lower temperatures it's so slow that we can act as if it has stopped completely.

As the device heats up, diffusion will get faster, until at some temperature, diffusion would destroy the device structure in some number of years. Manufacturers specify their maximum operating temperature a good margin below that.

That temperature depends on the materials used. Silicon, and the dopants used for making mass market things like logic and processors, haven't changed for several decades. What has changed is the size of the transistors. As the dimensions decrease, they become more sensitive to over-diffusion, so you might expect modern electronics to have slightly lower maximum specified operating temperatures than older ones. Only a slight difference, as the exponential dependence on temperature is so vicious.

Of course if you change the materials, like using silicon carbide or diamond instead of silicon, then the diffusion temperatures can increase. The original transistor material germanium had horribly low diffusion temperatures, and could not be machine soldered. I once destroyed a germanium transistor by using it as a diode to measure temperature, and went up to 100°C. That would have been fine with silicon.